# Динамическое создание компонента и выгрузка текста из файла в него

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

У меня есть файл.txt в котором содержится следующее:

```
@ Тест "Название теста" @  
%1. Вопрос теста  %
~ 1) вариант ответа 
 2) вариант ответа 
 3) вариант ответа 
 4) вариант ответа ~
1 (правильный вариант)
```

Если стоят символы '@' - то это заголовок теста выгружаемый в Edit, если '%' - то это вопрос выгружаемый в Memo, если '~' - то это варианты ответа выгружаемые в RadioGroup.
Вопросов в тест.txt может быть различное количество.

Что мне нужно сделать: программа должна считать файл и в зависимости от того, какой идет символ, вставить компонент на форму и вывести текст в компонент до такого же следующего символа.

Вот пример того как попробовал вывести заголовок путем выгрузки файла.txt в Memo, а из Memo в ранее созданный компонент Edit:

```
for k:=0 to Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do                  
    begin
      if AnsiPos('@', Memo1.Lines[k])<>0 then
        begin
          Edit1.Text :=  Memo1.Lines.Strings[k];
        end;
        if AnsiPos('@', Memo1.Lines[k]) = 1  then break;
    end;
```

Не могу создать компоненты и вывести вопросы и варианты ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Как динамически создать контрол на форме:

```
procedure TForm1.MyControlsCreate;
var
  lbl: TLabel;
begin
  lbl := TLabel.Create(Self);
  lbl.Parent := Self;
  lbl.Left := 80;
  lbl.Top := 16;
  lbl.Caption := 'My Label';
end;
```